# Repair Mountpoint

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

Hi guys i made a big mistake yesterday.

I tried to mount my microSD to /home/username/ with the diskutil Tool from Ubuntu 16.04.

But i took the wrong parition, so i mounted my EXT4 Ubuntu Partition from the internal SD, to /home/username/.

Now i can't startX anymore, it just boots to the terminal.
when i write DIR in the terminal it shows me all the Home folders like Downloads/Documents.

The wrong mounted partition is mmcblk0p2.

How can i solve this?

Content of /etc/fstab

```
# / was on /dev/mmcblk0p1 during installation

# swap was on /dev/mmcblk0p3 during installation
UUID=18f84a37-86a0-4bf4-9a63-138182ea903a none swap sw 0 0

UUID=F081-D9E7 /boot/efi vfat umask=0077,x-gvfs-show 0 1

UUID=bf4d33b3-6fce-4314-a686-25cfa72b4faf /home/nrg/sdcard ext4 errors=remount-ro,noauto 0 1
```

Comment: The most simple way would be a reboot if you just did a normal temporary mount.

Comment: it's not a temporary mount, i changed in diskutil the mountpoint

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the content of your `/etc/fstab` file please? You get it by running e.g. `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: ok, the wrong rooted drive is on /home/nrg/sdcard.

Comment: Yeah baby i solved it :), i remounted the filesystem to do it writeable with this command: mount -rw -o remount /

then i edited the /etc/fstab with sudo nano /etc/fstab and changed the line with /home/nrg/sdcard to /

Now i rebooted and everything is working again.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @niltuen Nice that you found a solution yourself. Would you mind posting it as a short answer below, not as comment, so that future readers can also profit from it? You can also later accept your own answer. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I remounted the file system to do it writable with this command:

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

Then I edited the `/etc/fstab` with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and changed the line  `/home/nrg/sdcard` to `/`.

Now I rebooted and everything is working again. Thanks for your time.